# функция использует замыкания?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Article() {
  Article.count++;

  //...
}
Article.count = 0;

Article.showCount = function() {
  alert( this.count ); // (1)
}

// использование
new Article();
new Article();
Article.showCount(); // (2)
```

Comment: Нет, не использует. Какое место в коде вызывает у Вас подозрения?

Comment: Рекомендую к прочтению: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: @Igor если там count++ а мы его не объявили значит поиск будет в window правильно ?

Comment: @meine  я в курсе замыкания я спросил ведь Article() функция; функция - конструктор

Comment: @Igor ведь Article() функция; функция - конструктор

Comment: @Igor  хотя если так window вернет нам undefined;

Comment: В показанном вами коде нет count++, зато есть Article.count++, который обращается к конкретному объекту Article без всяких замыканий и без всяких window

Comment: @Igor я кажись понял что происходит в коде 1) функция это объект 2) нет разницы какой синтаксис мы используем литерал или нет;3) мы присвоили в caunt  = 0; 4) Article.count++; тут используется Reference Type. значит число увеличится правильно ?

Comment: @Igor ваш ответ прочитал позже

Comment: @Igor так как мы 2 использовали new Article(); то Article.showCount(); покажет 2 верно ?

Comment: @xes Да, он покажет столько, сколько раз выполнилась функция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замыкания в этом коде нет.

Функция в js - это объект. У этого объекта Вы создали свойство

```
Article.count = 0;
```

При вызове этой функции (не важно, как конструктора или нет) значение этого свойства увеличивается.

При вызове

```
Article.showCount();
```

`this` внутри `showCount` это функция/объект `Article`, у которого есть созданное Вами свойство `count`.